# how can I close up the space in a table of images?

Tags: html

This is for a dense display of status information. Preferrably I would like to make the images butt up against each other.  Where is the extra white space coming from?

Here's what the generated table elements look like:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><small>anim-dept</small></td>
<td>
  <a href="http://foo/bar">
    <img height="24" width="32" src="http://foo/bar.jpg">
  </a>
</td>
....
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show the rest of the table's html and any related css?  Specifically show the starting table tag.

Comment: updated... nothing on the table, and no css as this is generated from a template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `TABLE`'s `CELLSPACING` and `CELLPADDING` to zero.
Note that you may need to add padding style to the first table row cells.

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td><small>anim-dept</small></td>
<td>
  <a href="http://foo/bar">
    <img height="24" width="32" src="http://foo/bar.jpg">
  </a>
</td>
....
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `border-collapse:collapse` in the css for the table as follows

```
table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

or only for an specific table with id `images`

```
table#images{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

Or (if you have no css)

```
<table cellspacing="0">
```

**DEMOS:** [**without border-collapse**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/Ate6D/1/) and [**with border-collapse**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/Ate6D) and [**without css but cellspaacing**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/Ate6D/)

Comment: You should also explicitly set table{width:0px;} and td {padding:0;border:none} to override any browser-native styling.

Comment: I agree and assumed/guessed there are already `css rules` applied for that but thanks, `OP`  will get an idea from the comment!

Answer (score 2):

This might not be an optimal solution, but I was able to fix this by adding:

```
tr {
    display:inline-block;
    height:24px;
}
```

The css `border-collapse: collapse` only seems to work for columns, rows still have spacing.  Setting the rows to inline-blocks instead of table-rows seems to fix it, although as I said it is probably not the best solution.